# Error during constructing the argument parse and parsing the arguments

Tags: python

I am getting some errors while running the following script of a drowsiness detection alert system, mainly during the argument parsing section

I have already tried to save the file (shape predictor) in the same location as the code.

[Code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1hL7.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please post your code snippet instead of adding a screenshot of the screen.

Comment: Also, if i recall correctly, argparse does not work in Jupyter. Try running it in a .py file and executing from the command line